# Are golang channels based on LIFO?

Tags: go, channel, fifo, lifo

I was wondering regarding the order of elements in golang channels. After running a few examples, it seems that the order in which the elements come off the channel is "last in first out". Am I right?

The following snippet is the example which I used. After running the code, the output is 20 10, while 10 was sent to the channel first and 20 last.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func multiply(c chan int, num int) {
    c <- num * 10
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)

    go multiply(c, 1)
    go multiply(c, 2)

    v1 := <-c
    v2 := <-c
    fmt.Println(v1, v2)
}
```

Comment: Note that the two goroutines could execute in either order: there's no particular reason to expect that 10 will be sent first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Golang channels are not LIFO.

> Channels act as first-in-first-out queues. For example, if one
>   goroutine sends values on a channel and a second goroutine receives
>   them, the values are received in the order sent.

Values sent on the channel will be received whenever the receiver of the channel is ready. And if not then it will block. For managing that you can go for buffered channels.

Below code will check if the values are available to be received from the channel.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func multiply(c chan int, num int) {
    c <- num * 10
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)

    go multiply(c, 1)
    go multiply(c, 2)
    go multiply(c, 3)

    for i:=0;i<3;i++{
         foo, ok := <- c
         if !ok {
                fmt.Println("done")
                return
         }
         fmt.Println(foo)
    }

}
```

Working code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/89K3sVSlue3)

**Buffered Channels**

Channels can be buffered. Provide the buffer length as the second argument to make to initialize a buffered channel:

```
make(chan int, 100)
```

> The capacity, in number of elements, sets the size of the buffer in
>   the channel. If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is
>   unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and
>   receiver are ready. Otherwise, the channel is buffered and
>   communication succeeds without blocking if the buffer is not full
>   (sends) or not empty (receives). A nil channel is never ready for
>   communication.

In your case, it depends on which go routine will send the value on the channel first. The values that you are printing completely depends on the go routines.

For more information go through [Golang Channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)

Comment: Why do you need ok? Something wrong could happen to chan?

Comment: Buffer channel might still be opened or closed. If ok is true it means channel is still open and if false it means channel is closed. Reading value from open channel is fine as long as channel has some value to be read, if no value then reading will pause. Reading from closed channel is also fine until some value is still there to be read, if no value then there is no PANIC instead zero value of channel type is returned. Now, as no panic happened how do we distinguish between zero value of type returned or 0 (if type is int for example). Thus ok idiom is used. This concept is similar to maps